# Copy all child when self lookup is created Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

Trigger required
I have **Program** as a *parent* 
**Program** **Module** as a child
**Program Intake** is having *self lookup* with Program
Now the scenario is When I create Self lookup(Program Intake) with Program All child (Program Module) should get copied to new self lookup record we created.
Any Help Appreciated!

```
 Trigger InsertProgrammeModules on Programme__c (after insert) {
 set<Id> programmeIds =new set<Id>();
 //list<Programme__c> programmeList =new list<Programme__c>();
 if(Trigger.isInsert){
 for(Programme__c pm:Trigger.new){
 programmeIds.add(pm.id);
```

Comment: Arshad, welcome to SFSE. if you can share your current trigger code or what you have tried so far and specify where exactly you got stuck, someone from the community can help you.

Comment: Thanx krishna for quick reply. I am very new to salesforce trigger . I have tried this much code

Comment: Just sum up: we are having selfrelation/hierarchy and want to copy all child Program_Module__c from parent/root Programme__c to any child Programme__c?
And whats the point of such action?

Comment: When Self relation is created I want to copy all child from that Programme_c

Comment: So if record P2 is created with lookup to P1, then you want to copy all the records of certain object under P1 to P2? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes Aslam. I am looking for the same